# Sample - ASP.NET MVC app with authentication for groups of users

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've read the very good articles about how to create secure ASP.NET MVC 5 web apps with Entity Framework 6 (e.g. [Create an ASP.NET MVC app with auth and ...](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/)) and as I'm new to this, I'm wondering how to take it a bit further.

The link above describes how to build an app where a user after being authenticated can access 'data' along with all other authenticated users - some users have admins rights so they can do more than others - but all users share the same set of 'data'.

I'm looking for an example where users can register themselves and then have their private set of 'data' - and invite other users (members) to share it. Only members - perhaps with different access rights (roles) - have access the private set of 'data'.

An example could be a database of movies (DVD, Blue ray, etc.) in the family. A family member would register the 'Family Smith's Movies', create the movies (title, genre, medium, rating, price, who bought it etc.) and invite the other family members to join. Younger family members cannot edit/create but only view.

This should of course be secure so non-members can't access 'data' for other users groups.

It sounds like a standard problem so I was wondering whether there are any good samples on how to do this properly?

Comment: Take a look at authorization on asp.net mvc and role management

Comment: As I understand it, role management allows me to assign different privileges to the users - not controlling which records belongs to whom.

Comment: this can be done using relationship between data and user who has a right to access it ,many to many maybe

Comment: I understand that I can make a relation between a GroupID that a user belongs to and a GroupID column in all tables. I suppose that views and controllers will have to filter on the GroupId to only show the private data.
As I'm new to this, I'm worried about making it secure?
And how to 'get' the GroupID in views and controllers where I need to filter on it?